# Redirection on htaccess, from subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

We moved our site from customize CMS to wordpress. It is multi-language website with couple of languages.

Example of page from old site, and how it is on the new site:

- on the previous CMS the languages was set like that: **ru.domain.com/articles/587**
- now, on Wordpress (with WMPL) it will be: **domain.com/ru/gelatti-de-marco-2/**

There are something like 10 pages that we need to do redirect from the old subdomain to the new subdomain, how we can do it from htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `ru.domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =ru.domain.com
RewriteRule ^articles/587/?$ http://domain.com/ru/gelatti-de-marco-2/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: thanks ! so if the site moved server, i need to create subdomain and go to the directory of the subdomain and create htaccess file with your instructions , right ?

Comment: Yes that is right (assuming `.htaccess` is enabled on subdomain).

Comment: it work for ru.domain.com, but if i want to add article id or slug to the "direct from" .. example: ru.domain.com/article/581/ .. it dont work for that.

Comment: As you can see above rule is for `/articles/587/` URI. You will need a separate rule for `/articles/581/` since your slug for `581` will also be different.